# nav2d exploration plugin

Tags: ros, nav2d-tutorials, nav2d-exploration, nav2d, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I see [nav2d](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d) comes with the ability to plugin exploration planners via pluginlib for cooperative exploration.  The source includes some example plugins.

I've gone through the nav2d tutorials as well as the [pluginlib tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin) but seem to be missing or overlooking a piece of basic information - how can I load and use one of the exploration planner plugins (of the three provided with the source) with the RobotNavigator?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221993/nav2d-exploration-plugin/) by [thekamz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25225/thekamz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Navigator](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d_navigator) has a parameter "exploration_strategy" to choose the strategy that is loaded at runtime.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0